# How To Generate Objects From A class whenever required?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I want to create objects from a class and store it in an array,as long as the user wants.Every time i want an object to be added in an array,i have to create it manually,and then store it in an array..is der a way that objects could be generated without creating it manually??

Comment: what do you mean by not creating objects manually? do you want to populate object in a loop or what?

Answer (score 1):

You would still, need to have some code which at some point instantiates the objects and sets its fields, however, you could write a small Class Factory (using the [Factory Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)) which will allow you to construct objects behind the scenes.